# Get url with controller name, action name and custom object with [FromQuery] attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm looking for an implementation for the GetUrl method in my example.

```
public class MyQueryObject
{
    [FromQuery]
    public string? Param1 { get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public int? Param2 { get; set; }
}
public class MyController: ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] MyQueryObject myQueryObject)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public string GetUrl(string controllerName, string actionName, object queryParamsObject)
{
    //im looking for an implementation here
}
```

So basically i would like to get the url for the correct action and extend the url with the query parameters. In other words i would like to generate an url for the action with the object, that ll result in the same object if i call the generated url.

For example: {root/controller/Action?Param1=Something} => Get the MyQueryObject with Param1 as Something, Param2 as null
and GetUrl("MyConroller", "Get", new MyQueryObject{ Param1 = "Something"}) => same url as above.

Also in other words, im looking for the inverse method of parsing the object from query string. It would be good if you can generate url from any object that can be parsed from the query. I would also like to highlight that many url ll result in the same object, so it is good enought to return one corrent solution.

Is there any built in implemetation for this?